# What is the efficient way to find connected components in Titan Graph

Tags: java, graph, graph-databases, titan

I will have a huge distributed graph. System doesn't know start vertex. I need to find connected components in this graph. Graph may have more than one components.
I am writing code in Java. 
So far the following line gives me nodes in one component

```
    final GremlinPipeline<Vertex,?> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Vertex>(v1).outE("connected").gather().scatter().inV().gather().scatter().inE("connected").gather().scatter().outV().gather().scatter();
```

But for this query I need to give start vertex. 
Is there any other efficient way to get all components of graph in Titan using Java without specifying start vertex. Also can I parallelize the work of finding components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use Titan-Hadoop for this problem:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/hadoop.html

Titan-Hadoop allows you to abstract MapReduce jobs behind Gremlin queries, allowing you to analyze an entire graph in multiple parallel jobs. Just using base Gremlin queries on Titan DB without a start index is going to be slow and difficult.